# java integration test with jetty jersey application with nebula graph database

Tags: java, integration-testing, graph-databases, assertion, nebula-graph

I have a Jetty HTTP Server to run a JAX-RS or Eclipse Jersey application.

I want to have an integration test with the Nebula graph

how can I implement tests with Nebula Graph as:

1. tests run in separate env (independent of local or production env)
2. my integration test run in nebula graph as docker or any other solution
3. my ci-cd runs those tests easily
4. my developers produce data and assert them after saving

Comment: have you checked this: https://github.com/nebula-contrib/ngbatis/tree/master/src/test yet? Basically it included a docker-compose and the kind of end to end test calls to the dockerized NebulaGraph cluster then.

Comment: thank you very much i want to ask questions from the nebula that I guess others asked and search for it by google in the future. when we have a simple sample of a nebula graph others enjoy and many developers want to use it. when we have good knowledge base others love this technology. I want to guess newbie developers like me. one of the KPIs is a number of StackOverflow questions and answers.

Comment: thanks so much Saber, maybe I should create an end to end example project like this.

Comment: I want to be a Nebula Graph promoter in some universities I have many students in telegram and I want to make cbt learning videos in Persian for them. I want to introduce Nebula for other University professors to use nebula graphs in research. so i need some samples and open-source cases.